# How to upload an image on a server using authorization and show the received json response in Android?

Tags: android, api, http, file-upload

I am new to Android. I want to upload an image to a server and show the received json response after some parsing.

I am trying to use Android upload service (refer: (1) https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server/
(2) https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service) but I don't know how to add authorization header in it. I tried to read the code in the github link, but couldn't understand.

The things I want to know are:

1. What is the best method to upload a file on a server using authorization.
2. Does Android provide something or is it better to use libraries? (I read that HttpURLConnection can help, but also read that it's better to use libraries for large files, but the source didn't look trustworthy, also I have lost from where I read that)
3. When I get through the uploading part, how do I approach the json part? (the uploading and response comes from a single url, I post the data in the request and it will give me some JSON response)
4. From where do I learn Android, so that I don't seek such spoon feeding answers.

The uploading code, in which I want to add authorization header:

```
public void uploadMultipart() {

    String name = "app_image";
    String path = getPath(filePath);

    try {
        String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, UPLOAD_URL)
                .addFileToUpload(path, "image")
                .addParameter("name", name)
                .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                .setMaxRetries(2)
                .startUpload();

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I took it from the first reference, I have one doubt in it too: `String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();`.

What is its purpose and why am I using it? I feel like it's not necessary in my case, as I want to upload images using authorized usernames and not anonymous users.

Comment: I think I should just ask the other parts individually instead of clubbing them in this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this Documentation](http://gotev.github.io/android-upload-service/javadoc/net/gotev/uploadservice/HttpUploadRequest.html#addHeader-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

I haven't myself used this library, but from what I can see here in the documentation you should be able add authorization with `.addHeader(String headerName,String headerValue)` This will add the Header to your request.

In your case you should do this if you have an access token:

```
new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, UPLOAD_URL)
            .addHeader("Authorization",<Put the authentication type here>+" "+<Put your access token here>)
            .addFileToUpload(path, "image")
            .addParameter("name", name)
            .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
            .setMaxRetries(2)
            .startUpload();
```

If you are trying to authorize with username password, replace `addHeader(String,String)` with `setBasicAuth(String username,String password)`

Coming to your second question.

The purpose of using uuid here is probably used by the library to keep track of your uploads. from what I see in the documentation if you don't pass the upload id. The library generates it for you. It is used internally by the library.

Comment: thanks, how did you find that documentation? Also, the server will send some data in response, how do I get that?

Comment: An [issue that was raised](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service/issues/104)  that's related to your query.

Comment: A simple google search will give you the documentation, and most functions have a description. You can then use find in page to easily get what you are looking for. If my answer solved your problem please accept it.

Comment: Your answer has definitely helped me out and I am grateful. However, I am waiting for answers on the other part of my question as well. So, I am thinking of giving it some time before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Retrofit and Gson library easy to handle your APIs

Retofit - http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Retrofit tutorial - https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client